# how can i merg a String array and boolean array

Tags: java, arrays

i have two array like this

```
String[][] name=new String[4][10];
boolean[] accun=new boolean[10];
name[0][0]="ali";
name[0][1]="max";
name[0][2]="ahmad";
etc.....
name[1][0]="9999";
name[1][1]="9999";
name[1][2]="9999";
etc...
and name[2][..] ,name[3][..] like that.
```

now how can i merge this two array together?like this.

```
name [5][0]=true;
name [0][0]="alex";
```

Thanks for your any Help.

Comment: ...what is this?  I don't even...  No seriously, I don't understand the kind of problem you're trying to solve, or what *good* it'd do to try and combine a String and boolean array together (not that you could nicely).

Comment: You can't do that. Your name array is 2D array of Strings only String objects can go into it, no boolean values can go into that array. You need to find a different solution to what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you explain why you want to do this you may find people offering a realistic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of an array is the same for all elements of an array.  The only way this would work for you is to use `Object[][]` because `Object` is a supertype of both `String` and `Boolean`.  However, what you should probably be doing is creating a class which has members which are currently being represented by the different indices of your array.  For example:

```
class Foo {
  String name;
  int count;
  boolean isFoo;
}

Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
foo[0] = new Foo();
foo[0].name = "aaaa";
foo[0].count = 9999;
foo[0].isFoo = true;
```

You should then also look into constructors and accessor methods to make the code more idiomatic Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit ambiguous.My assumption is you are trying to ask how to different type of objects in array. Here you should go

```
 Object[][] name = new Object[4][10];
```

Now you can store both int and string objects under name array.